# how do I correctly use case when statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

Hej,

I needed help with a case when statement in SQL Server.

Basically, I got three products and when the sum is equal to 2, then I want it to it be counted as 1 else 0. I wanted to know if the logic is write with this code or can it be improved?

case when sum(hase=1 OR hasd=1 OR hasf=1)=2 then 1 else 0 end as Xavc

What I was trying with this code is this: The customer might not have all three products however, if he has two products or the three the three , then it is equal to 2 and count is 1.

Comment: The syntax is wrong.  If you are using a sum function, you have to be adding up numbers.  Also your question is not clear.  You want to look at when the sum is equal to 2.  The sum of what?

Comment: I wnant to classify it. I got three products. If they have only 1 of 3 products, then Z type. If they got 2 out of 3 products, then sum=2 and they are customer C.

Comment: In that case it appears that SchmitzIT has provided the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN hase + hasd + hasf = 2 THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS Xavc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do something like this...

```
CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN hase=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        + SUM(CASE WHEN hasd=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        + SUM(CASE WHEN hasf=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Xavc
```

In this case try this ..

```
CASE WHEN  SUM(CASE WHEN hase=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN hasd=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
        OR SUM(CASE WHEN hasd=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN hasf=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2 
        OR SUM(CASE WHEN hase=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN hasf=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2 
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Xavc
```

Comment: if all the three cases were equal to 1 then it would still be a total 0f 2 which would be wrong.  Maybe I am not understanding it clearly. I thought OR clause is necessary.  Out of the 3 products, if they have 2 of three, then sum=2 and count 1.